# How to synchronize server operation in multiple instances web application on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, synchronization, client-server

I have a client-server web application - the client is HTML/JS and the server is ASP.Net. web application hosted by **Azure Web Role**
In this application the client can save a document on the server by calling a web service method on the server side.
After calling the saving method, the client might save the document again while the server processes his previous save request. In this case I want the newly initiated saving to be queued until the previous saving operation is completed.
If I had a single web role instance, it would be easy for me to implement this by thread synchronization, but since the client request might be handled by different web role instances, the synchronization is problematic.
My question is - how can I implement such synchronization mechanism, or is there a better way to get the same result, that I'm not aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an application for Azure Storage Queues.

Comment: I don't think Storage Queues solve this particular problem: The OP states that, in a multi-instance scenario, any additional *save* operations should wait until the previous operation completes. This won't be the case with Azure Queues where another instance can pick up an additional *save* queue message at the same time the original is being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider combination of storage or service bus queues to queue up the requests to process the documents AND using BLOB leases to mark the work as in progress.

Queuing would be important since the requests might be delayed in processing if there is a previous request for the same job that's on going.

BLOB Leasing is a way to put a centralized lock in storage.  Once you start processing of a request, you can put a blob with a lease on it and release the lease once you're done.  Requests for the same work would check first if the lease is available before kicking off.  Otherwise, they could just wait.  More info on leases here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/leasing-windows-azure-blobs-using-the-storage-client-library

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the [Windows Azure Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914128.aspx) - Co-Located on your roles?

This is a shared caching layer that can use excess memory on your roles (Or have it's own worker role if your web roles are already close to capacity) to create a key / value store which can be accessed by any role on the same deployment.

You could use the cache to store a value indicating a document is currently being processed and block it until the document has finished uploaded.  As it is a shared caching layer the value will be persisted across your instances (Though the cache will not persist during an upgrade deployment).

Here's a good introductary article to [using Caching in Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) with configuration examples and sample code.